# Hide DIV based on text value within DIV

Tags: jquery, hide, contains

I am fairly new to JQuery and am trying to hide the DIV #SAlertWrap when the contents of td.ms-vb contain the text "There are currently no active announcements". td.ms-vb is contained within #SAlertWrap.

I can hide the DIV itself but cannot figure out how to hide it based on the text value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#SAlertWrap').hide( );
});
```

I can also select the text to hide or replace the text, but that only effects that particular row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("td.ms-vb:contains('There are currently no active announcements')").parent().hide();
});
```

I tried replacing parent() with $('#SAlertWrap') and kept getting syntax errors.

Any ideas on how to combine these?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your method, but with .[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) with the optional selector. If your td is not an immediate child use [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td.ms-vb:contains('There are currently no active announcements')")
   .parents('#SAlertWrap').hide();
});
```

A slight performance improvement may be to use [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of parents.

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly how I wanted. I'll read up into the .parents() method to learn more of how to use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("td.ms-vb").text() == 'There are currently no active announcements') {
    $("td.ms-vb").parent().hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: This will only test the first `td.ms-vb`, and then hide _all_ of them depending on that TD's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if ( $("td.ms-vb:contains('There are currently no active announcements')").length )
    $('#SAlertWrap').hide( );
```

`.length` checks the array of matching elements provided by your selector. If the length is greater than 0, then hide your element. (`0` is falsy in JS)